# In spark how can I render histogram with list of elements in different group?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, histogram, databricks

I was trying to compare two list of elements visually in spark on databricks. My data looks like the following,

```
+--------+-----------------------------------+
|  Status|                MyList             |
+--------+-----------------------------------+
|  OK    |[Z186, D689, P12, P12, P12, P5,....|
|Cancel  |[Z186, P12, Z87, P12, P5, P5,   ...|
+--------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to be able to draw two frequency graph (like bar chart, histogram) -- sorted and positioned stacked. How can achieve that using display() function in the Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw two individual histograms, one for each row. Here is some code you can adapt:

```
%sql

select data, count(*) from (
select explode(array_data) as data from (
    select array(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1) as array_data
  )
)
group by data
order by data
```

[image]